# Cadena "ISO8601 date string" a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, date, datetime, fullcalendar

Buenas. 
Estoy trabajando con FullCalendar. Cuando creo un evento, me devuelve una cadena  "ISO8601 date string", me gustaría traducirlo a PHP (date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))

Se que para convertir a una cademna ISO8601 es date("c",strotime($date)), pero digamos que lo que quiero hacer es al reves.

El problema es cuando hago lo siguiente:

```
$cadenaenISO8601 = "1508112000000";
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strotime($cadena);
```

o

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", intval($cadena);
```

Me devuelve valores erróneos.

**Edito:
$task si devuelve, de todas maneras no tiene nada que ver y no lo debería de haber puesto, ya que solo genera confusión. El tema es que cuando pincho en un día para crear un evento, me devuelve start y end, con la cadena que pongo más abajo**

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
    locale: '<?php echo $locale ?>',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end) {

        window.location="{{ url('task_create') }}"+"/"+start+"/"+end;
    },

    editable: true,
    height:650,
    events : [


    ]
})
```

});

**Con esta cadena:**

```
Start: string(13) "1508198400000"

End: string(13) "1508284800000"
```

Comment: ¿Esto es un valor datetime en formato ISO8601: `1508112000000`? La verdad que no me entero de nada. [No veo ninguna posibilidad de representación de fecha de esa manera](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Fechas_y_horas_conjuntas) en el formato ISO8601.

Comment: Cuando utilizo EventData en FullCalendar, StartParam me devuelve una cadena tal que así.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/startParam/

Comment: Es muy extraño que devuelva una fecha así, la cual es posiblemente una fecha Unix Timestamp, no es una fecha ISO. ¿Tienes tu librería [actualizada a la versión 3.6.1](https://fullcalendar.io/download/)? En la versión 1 [según la doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/startParam/), te devuelve fechas como las de tu ejemplo, no así en la nueva versión.

Comment: Si, he actualizado a 3.6.1 y me sigue devolviendo:
   Start: string(13) "1508198400000"
  End:  string(13) "1508284800000"

Comment: Será útil que pongas el código donde usas `startParam` [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/110346/edit), no en una respuesta, porque eso no es una respuesta.

Comment: ¿Tú has hecho un `var_dump($tasks);`  para ver lo que hay dentro?. Pareciera que no está encontrando nada. No entiendo del todo tu código, pero...  ¿seguro que dentro de `$tasks` hay una clave llamada `date_start` y otra llamada `date_end`. ¿No se llamarán `start` y `end`? Yo no veo donde asignas las claves `date_start` y `date_end`  a ese posible array.

Comment: no veo por que te complicas con eso. por que no formateas la fecha en javascript y la envias formateada

Comment: El tema es que yo esas cadenas las tengo que insertar en UTC con un formato "Y-m-d G:i:s", por lo que es más comodo para mi hacerlo en PHP. Pero ya que estoy pregunto. ¿Que manera hay en JS para que me de ese formato? Utilice Date.parse pero no lo conseguí.